# After use "first_as_label" option contact form 7 validation not working

Tags: wordpress

I have used Contact form 7 and this syntax [select* time first_as_label "Select Time" "10:00 am" "10:30 am" "11:00 am" "11:30 am"] to display time in a drop down. But the validation not working.

Comment: Can you share more details? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Did you use CF7 to create the shortcode?

Comment: Hi, Yes I have created a time drop-down here is the short-code [select* time first_as_label "Select Time" "10:00 am" "10:30 am" "11:00 am" "11:30 am"]

Comment: Yes I am using CF7